# Python html parsing partial class names

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a webpage with bs4 but the elements I am trying to access all have different class names. 
Example: class='list-item listing … id-12984' and class='list-item listing … id-10359'

```
def preownedaston(url):
    preownedaston_resp = requests.get(url)

    if preownedaston_resp.status_code == 200:
        bs = BeautifulSoup(preownedaston_resp.text, 'lxml')
        posts = bs.find_all('div', class_='') #don't know what to put here
        for p in posts:
            title_year = p.find('div', class_='inset').find('a').find('span', class_='model_year').text
            print(title_year)

preownedaston('https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/search/?finance%5B%5D=price&price-currency%5B%5D=EUR&custom-model%5B404%5D%5B%5D=809&continent-country%5B%5D=France&postcode-area=United%20Kingdom&distance%5B%5D=0&transmission%5B%5D=Manual&budget-program%5B%5D=pay&section%5B%5D=109&order=-usd_price&pageId=3760')
```

Is there a way to parse a partial class name like `class_='list-item '`?

Comment: I don't think your code even gets to a point where the elements you look for even exist. Look at the source code of that page: `view-source:https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/search/?finance%5B%5D=price&price-currency%5B%5D=EUR&custom-model%5B404%5D%5B%5D=809&continent-country%5B%5D=France&postcode-area=United%20Kingdom&distance%5B%5D=0&transmission%5B%5D=Manual&budget-program%5B%5D=pay&section%5B%5D=109&order=-usd_price&pageId=3760`. I can't find any `list-item` in that source code, and Beautifulsoup won't, either.

Comment: @Tomalak I find two divs that represent the 'posts' (one for each car) and each one has a class that resembles :  'list-item listing usedVehiclesSearch usedvehicles usedcars make-aston-martin model-v12-vantage reg-s00754 location-3d81f6e3a2cfd67ead2b23e36fab68948d711d43 h-3d81f6e3a2cfd67ead2b23e36fab68948d711d43 aston-martin-bordeaux franchise-628fa2b4b3ef528010bde94a132f98717eb30c45 h-628fa2b4b3ef528010bde94a132f98717eb30c45 id-10359'

Comment: Not when you look at the page's source code. You are looking at the live DOM in your browser's development tools, that's a _completely_ different thing. Beautifulsoup will not see that, because all of this is Javascript-generated, and Beautifulsoup does not run any Javascript. Use the `view-source:` link (copy & paste) to see what Beautifulsoup will see.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for this, I didn't know that you needed the source code directly to parse the page as all my previous scripts used the DOM. I managed to locate where the details for each car is but how to I access them with bs4 ? (sorry still very noobish)

Comment: @Tomalak Nevermind, the other answers explained it quite well, thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css Selector for matching a partial value of a certain attribute is as follows :

```
div[class*='list-item'] # the * means match the class with this partial value
```

But if you look at the source code of the page you will see that the content you are trying to scrape is being generated by Javascript So you have three options here

1. Use Selenium with a headless browser to render the javescript
2. Look for the Ajax calls and try to simulate them for example this url is the ajax call the website uses to retrieve the data  [Ajax URL](https://preowned.astonmartin.com/ajax/stock-listing/get-items/pageId/3760/ratio/3_2/taxBandImageLink/aHR0cHM6Ly9kMnBwMTFwZ29wNWY2cC5jbG91ZGZyb250Lm5ldC9UYXhCYW5kLSV0YXhfYmFuZCUuanBn/taxBandImageHyperlink/JWRlYWxlcl9lbWFpbCU=/imgWidth/767/?finance%5B%5D=price&price-currency%5B%5D=EUR&custom-model%5B404%5D%5B%5D=809&continent-country%5B%5D=France&distance%5B%5D=0&transmission%5B%5D=Manual&budget-program%5B%5D=pay&section%5B%5D=109&order=-usd_price&pageId=3760)
3. Look for the data you are trying to scrape into a script tag as follows :

I prefer this one in similar situation because you will be parsing Json

```
import requests , json 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/search/?finance%5B%5D=price&price-currency%5B%5D=EUR&custom-model%5B404%5D%5B%5D=809&continent-country%5B%5D=France&postcode-area=United%20Kingdom&distance%5B%5D=0&transmission%5B%5D=Manual&budget-program%5B%5D=pay&section%5B%5D=109&order=-usd_price&pageId=3760'

page = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
json_obj = soup.find('script',{'type':"application/ld+json"}).text
#{"@context":"http://schema.org","@graph":[{"@type":"Brand","name":""},{"@type":"OfferCatalog","itemListElement":[{"@type":"Offer","name":"Pre-Owned By Aston Martin","price":"€114,900.00","url":"https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/12984-aston-martin-v12-vantage-v8-volante/","itemOffered":{"@type":"Car","name":"Aston Martin V12 Vantage V8 Volante","brand":"Aston Martin","model":"V12 Vantage","itemCondition":"Used","category":"Used","productionDate":"2010","releaseDate":"2011","bodyType":"6.0 Litre V12","emissionsCO2":"388","fuelType":"Obsidian Black","mileageFromOdometer":"42000","modelDate":"2011","seatingCapacity":"2","speed":"190","vehicleEngine":"6l","vehicleInteriorColor":"Obsidian Black","color":"Black"}},{"@type":"Offer","name":"Pre-Owned By Aston Martin","price":"€99,900.00","url":"https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/10359-aston-martin-v12-vantage-carbon-edition-coupe/","itemOffered":{"@type":"Car","name":"Aston Martin V12 Vantage Carbon Edition Coupe","brand":"Aston Martin","model":"V12 Vantage","itemCondition":"Used","category":"Used","productionDate":"2011","releaseDate":"2011","bodyType":"6.0 Litre V12","emissionsCO2":"388","fuelType":"Obsidian Black","mileageFromOdometer":"42000","modelDate":"2011","seatingCapacity":"2","speed":"190","vehicleEngine":"6l","vehicleInteriorColor":"Obsidian Black","color":"Black"}}]},{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":"1","item":{"@id":"https://preowned.astonmartin.com/","name":"Homepage"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":"2","item":{"@id":"https://preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/","name":"Pre-Owned Cars"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":"3","item":{"@id":"//preowned.astonmartin.com/preowned-cars/search/","name":"Pre-Owned By Aston Martin"}}]}]}
items = json.loads(json_obj)['@graph'][1]['itemListElement']
for item in items :
    print(item['itemOffered']['name'])
```

Output:

```
Aston Martin V12 Vantage V8 Volante
Aston Martin V12 Vantage Carbon Edition Coupe
```

Answer (score 2):

The information from this URL actually comes back in JSON format which means you can easily extract the fields you want. For example:

```
import requests

url = "https://preowned.astonmartin.com/ajax/stock-listing/get-items/pageId/3760/ratio/3_2/taxBandImageLink/aHR0cHM6Ly9kMnBwMTFwZ29wNWY2cC5jbG91ZGZyb250Lm5ldC9UYXhCYW5kLSV0YXhfYmFuZCUuanBn/taxBandImageHyperlink/JWRlYWxlcl9lbWFpbCU=/imgWidth/767/?finance%5B%5D=price&price-currency%5B%5D=EUR&custom-model%5B404%5D%5B%5D=809&continent-country%5B%5D=France&distance%5B%5D=0&transmission%5B%5D=Manual&budget-program%5B%5D=pay&section%5B%5D=109&order=-usd_price&pageId=3760"

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
details = ['make', 'mileage', 'model', 'model_year', 'mpg', 'exterior_colour', 'price_now']

for vehicle in data['vehicles']:
    print()
    for key in details:
        print(f"{key:18} : {vehicle[key]}")
```

This displays the following:

```
make               : Aston Martin
mileage            : 42,000 km
model              : V12 Vantage
model_year         : 2011
mpg                : 17.3
exterior_colour    : Carbon Black
price_now          : €114,900

make               : Aston Martin
mileage            : 42,000 km
model              : V12 Vantage
model_year         : 2011
mpg                : 17.3
exterior_colour    : Carbon Black
price_now          : €99,900
```

Note: it might be necessary to add a user agent request header if the data is not returned. If you display `data` you can see all of the available information for each vehicle.

This approach avoids the need to have javascript processing via Selenium and also avoids needing to parse any HTML using BeautifulSoup. The URL was found using the browser's network tools whilst the page was loading.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer !